# how to print forms.ValidationError in django

Tags: django, forms

found this in a tutorial but "password and confirm_password does not match" is not printing to html page.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password','confirm_password']

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "password and confirm_password does not match"
        )
```

UPDATE:
Worked using {{form.non_field_errors}} in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Numerous way you can do it,from your views,forms also from your model

```
Class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
pass

    def clean_password(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords must be same')
```

BTW
If using Python 3.6 then super().method_name(args),
if using 2.7 then super(class_name,self).method_name(args)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "password and confirm_password does not match"
        )
    else:
        form = UserForm()
        # If form is not valid, this would re-render 
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```